# How to bind list to TreeView to achive multilevel

Tags: c#, sql, wpf, entity-framework, treeview

I want to bind list to TreeView. But it should work like that:

I work with entity framework. In easiest case I have 2 tables with 2 associations.

Customer
Product

Customer is connected with itself
Customer.CustomerID - Customer.ParentID
and 
Product.CustomerID - Customer.CustomerID

Right now I want to populate TreeView and achieve something like this:

```
Customer1
    SubCustomer1
        Product1
        Product2
    Product3
Customer2
    Product4
Customer3
    SubCustomer2
        Product5
    SubCustomer3
        SubCustomer4
             Product6
        Product7
    Product8
```

I want to see only Name properties and somehow detect which one is clicked.

Customer Table has 3 navigation properties
Products
CustomerChildren
CustomerParent

Product table has 3 navigation properties but I don't want to use it in TreeView.

In runtime I want to click on some Product, detect that Product is selected (stop if customer is selected) and then make some database modification according to other controls.

Can someone help?

Comment: Have you tried using HierarchicalDataTemplate? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.hierarchicaldatatemplate(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: I didn't try but I will. I am reading this article right now.

Answer (score 0):

I read through what you wrote 4 times now and i still dont know exactly what you want. But i guess some things that i think i picked up:

- For detecting which node is clicked: You add a NodeMouseClick event to the treeView and get the node you want with e.Node then if you want you can just e.Node.Name to get the name and check if it has "product" in it, otherwise you can also assign a key to each node and check through that. I dont exactly know what you mean with stop if customer is selected, stop the program??
- For populating the treeView read the data from your database and add it to a class that looks something like this

.

```
public class className{
    public string nodeName;
    public className parent;
    public List<className> child;
}
```

Then populate the treeView with a recursive function that starts at the root of this class:

```
public void populateTree(className c){
    treenode tn;
    if(c doesnt exists in treeView)
        tn = new node c in treeview
    else
        tn = node index of c
    foreach child in c.child
        TreeNode tnChild = add every child of c to this node
        populateTree(child)
}
```

Comment: I used wrong word. Stop executing code. Something like 
if(SelectedNode is Product)
//some code
else
return;

Comment: After several tries with HierarchicalDataTemplate I just wrote recursive function that populate TreeView with TreeViewItem and then TreeViewItem.Items with another TreeViewItem.